# String.Format way to format Currency without Cents

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I'm displaying currency using the current method

```
String.Format("{0:C}", item.DonationAmount)
```

Which outputs like $10.00

We will be dealing with large dollar amounts, and no cents. We would like the currency to display as $10 without the decimal or zeroes. How can I do this? Removing the currency format makes the number display like 10.0000 :( thanks in advance.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Specify you want zero decimal places:

```
String.Format("{0:C0}", item.DonationAmount)
```

Comment: This adds a "C" in front of cents. FYI. Use c0 to avoid this.

Comment: I'm not seeing a "C" in front - https://dotnetfiddle.net/0hCG6f - and the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8) say "C" is equivalent to "c"- do you have a reproducible example of it? What culture are you using?

Comment: Note: `c0` rounds to the nearest dollar, with 9.50 rounding up to 10.

Answer (score 24):

if `item.DonationAmount` is a `non-nullable` `decimal` then you could just do:

```
item.DonationAmount.ToString("c0");
```

if `item.DonationAmount` is a `nullable` `decimal` that you checked has a value then you could do:

```
item.DonationAmount.Value.ToString("c0");
```

or in a newer version of `C#`, which doesn't require you to check if it has a value:

```
item.DonationAmount?.ToString("c0");
```

Comment: Very useful to know. Do you know which version of C# added support for the `item.DonationAmount?.ToString("c0");` example?

Comment: Based on some googling, it seems to be `C# 6.0`

Comment: Note: `c0` does round to the nearest dollar, with 9.50 rounding up to 10.

Answer (score 6):

```
  decimal value = 0.00M;
        value = Convert.ToDecimal(12345.12345);
        Console.WriteLine(".ToString(\"C\") Formates With Currency $ Sign");
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C"));
        //OutPut : $12345.12
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C1"));
        //OutPut : $12345.1
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C2"));
        //OutPut : $12345.12
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C3"));
        //OutPut : $12345.123
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C4"));
        //OutPut : $12345.1235
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C5"));
        //OutPut : $12345.12345
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C6"));
        //OutPut : $12345.123450
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(".ToString(\"F\") Formates With out Currency Sign");
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("F"));
        //OutPut : 12345.12
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("F1"));
        //OutPut : 12345.1
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("F2"));
        //OutPut : 12345.12
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("F3"));
        //OutPut : 12345.123
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("F4"));
        //OutPut : 12345.1235
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("F5"));
        //OutPut : 12345.12345
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("F6"));
        //OutPut : 12345.123450

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(".ToString(\"N\") Formates With out Currency Sign");
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("N"));
        //OutPut : 12,345.12
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("N1"));
        //OutPut : 12,345.1
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("N2"));
        //OutPut : 12,345.12
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("N3"));
        //OutPut : 12,345.123
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("N4"));
        //OutPut : 12,345.1235
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("N5"));
        //OutPut : 12,345.12345
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("N6"));
        //OutPut : 12,345.123450

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(".ToString(\"P\") Formates With Percentage (i.e multiply by 100)");
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("P"));
        //OutPut : 1,2345,12.35%
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("P1"));
        //OutPut : 1,2345,12.3%
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("P2"));
        //OutPut : 12345,12.35%
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("P3"));
        //OutPut : 12345,12.345%
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("P4"));
        //OutPut : 12345,12.3450%
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("P5"));
        //OutPut : 12345,12.34500%
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("P6"));
        //OutPut : 12345,12.345000%


        Console.Read();
```

[Click to see Console Out Put Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Yra.png)

Hope this may Help you...

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Variation: formatting without cents, but only if `cents == 0`

Using `c0` will round to the nearest dollar. So `15` and `14.95` both become `$15`

If instead you wanted to only hide cents if it is `$.00` you can use this:

```
value.ToString("c").Replace(".00", "")
```

That gives values like `$15` and `$14.95`

If there's a better way please comment!